# Fill boost::unordered_set quickly

Tags: c++, boost, containers, mlpack, boost-unordered

I am trying to construct as quick as possible a set of elements based on the result of an image classification.

In the details, I would like to store in this set all the (r, g, b) pixels which belong to a certain class. The problem has 2 classes, I would like to retain the pixels which are from class 1 and discard the pixels from class 0.
The classification is done using a trained `mlpack` classifier on a (r, g, b) vector of double.

I have to use a `boost::unordered_set<uint32_t>` for this task or similar.
The code up to now looks like this

```
boost::unordered_set<uint32_t> bset;

for (int r = 0; r < 256; r++)
{
    for (int g = 0; g < 256; g++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < 256; b++)
        {
            arma::rowvec xp = { (double)b, (double)g, (double)r };
            if ((bool)(clf.Classify(xp))) {
                uint32_t cachePos = r + (g << 8) + (b << 16);
                bset.insert(cachePos);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I have made some benchmarks and the slowest part is the insertion with `insert()`. To scan all the possible (r, g, b) it takes about 5 seconds. Since the code is called from a GUI I would like it to be faster to reduce the time a user has to wait for the result.

First I tried to change `.insert()` with `.emplace()` but as I expected there is little improvement.

I also tried filling another container, actually `std::vector` was quite fast, and the copying its content in the set using iterators:

```
std::vector<int> predictions;
for (int r = 0; r < 256; r++)
{
    for (int g = 0; g < 256; g++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < 256; b++)
        {
            arma::rowvec xp = { (double)b, (double)g, (double)r };
            if ((bool)(clf.Classify(xp))) {
                uint32_t cachePos = r + (g << 8) + (b << 16);
                predictions.push_back(cachePos);
            }

        }
    }
}

bset = boost::unordered_set<uint32_t>(predictions.begin(), predictions.end());
```

But still, the last line takes a lot of time, around 2-3 seconds. Do you have any hint for me?
What can I do to improve the speed of my code? Are there faster container that I can use to replace `boost::unordered_set` ? The container should contain elements from class 1 only.

Comment: Do you have to store it in `boost::unordered_set` at the end? [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) might be an option.

Comment: What is the final size of the set? Each time I made benchmarks to compare `std::set` with `std::unordered_set`, I found that the first one was faster. But I didn't made these tests with an infinite size! I limited these tests for sizes up to 10^7.

Comment: @Jarod42 I can't use std::bitset because the set size can change. But I tried `boost::dynamic_bitset` and it is quite fast. The point is (for what I understand) is that bitset is a set of 0s and 1s. I can't figure how to store all and only the (r, g, b) of class 1 with that. How would you do that? I can't just push_back when I find a member of class 1

Comment: @Damien I didn't try `std::set` but its an idea! As I answered above, the size isn't fixed. It depends on the result of the classification. Also the set is passed as reference to a function which uses the piece of code I posted and is sometimes modified outside of it.

Comment: Note that by modifyng the order of the loops, you will get a `vector` which is already sorted. I don't know if you would have the possibility to simply use this ordered array. If not, it might help creating rapidly a `std::set`, to be checked.

Comment: I meant for the `std::bitset` version, you have `256*256*256` (`16777216`) combinations, so `2097152` bits (with index `r + (g << 8) + (b << 16)`) (huge (fixed-size) array, but less than regular sets in worst case).

Comment: @Damien I have to use set. But swapping "r" with "b" helped a lot: I gained almost 1 second. I didn't grasp it but using a sorted vector always helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since unordered_set can not predict number of elements to be inserted, it performs allocation and insertion for each particular element. In your case it's exactly 256 x 256 x 256 = 16,777,216 times. The bottleneck in this situation is memory allocation. Since vector consumes memory by chunks - it inserts much faster.
The solution is to use the 'reserve' method:

```
boost::unordered_set<uint32_t> bset;
bset.reserve(256*256*256);

for (int r = 0; r < 256; r++)
{
    for (int g = 0; g < 256; g++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < 256; b++)
        {
            arma::rowvec xp = { (double)b, (double)g, (double)r };
            if ((bool)(clf.Classify(xp))) {
                uint32_t cachePos = r + (g << 8) + (b << 16);
                bset.insert(cachePos);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot reserve that much space because (I didn't mention it before) in a real world problem I can have up to 16 sets at the same time (not taking into account the memory needed for the UI), and therefore I don't want to save space for all the possible (r, g, b) s but only for those who are classified as members of class 1.

Comment: Insert into a vector and preserve memory only for vector::size() elements.
Or - if it is possible to pre estimate count of elements to be inserted - reserve at least half of that amount.
One more solution - use custom allocator that consume memory by chunks.